# c#: try/catch how to clear the text box that caused the error?

Tags: c#, exception

Im wondering if theres a way to have the catch statement clear the text box that caused the error. Here's my validation code so far:

```
private bool ValidateForm()
{
    int val1, direction = 0;
    double speed = 0.0;

    bool validated = false;

    if (txtName.Text != "")
    {
        try
        {
            // attempts to convert values into their primary data types.
            // Any errors will throw an exception that will be reported
            // as invalid data

            val1 = Convert.ToInt32(txtXPos.Text);
            val1 = Convert.ToInt32(txtYPos.Text);
            speed = Convert.ToDouble(txtSpeed.Text);
            direction = Convert.ToInt32(txtDirection.Text);

            validated = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show(
              "You have an invalid value entered. Please check your entry.",
              "Invalid Values", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        if (speed < 0.0 || speed > (double)newAirplane.PlanePosition.MaxSpeed)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(
              "Speed entered is out of range.",
              "Invalid Values", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        if (direction < 0 || direction > 359) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show(
              "Direction is out of range",
              "Invalid values", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(
            "Please enter a name.",
            "Blank Name", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    return validated;
}
```

Comment: Maybe look into using Int32.TryParse instead of using exceptions. Or even better, prevent users from even typing in values that are wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest making a function like,

```
private bool TryReadClear(TextBox txtBox, out double value)
{
  if (double.TryParse(txtBox.Text, out value))
  {
    txtBox.BackColor = Color.White;
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    txtBox.BackColor = Color.Red;
    txtBox.Text = string.Empty;
    return false;
  }
}
```

and then replace your try/catch block with this simplified code:

```
    validated = validated && TryReadClear(txtXPos, out val1);
    validated = validated && TryReadClear(txtYPos, out val1);
    validated = validated && TryReadClear(txtSpeed, out speed);
    validated = validated && TryReadClear(txtDirection, out direction);
    if (!validated)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("You have an invalid value entered. Please check your entry.", "Invalid Values", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
```

The benefit of this method is that it will check **all** text boxes each pass, and clear all the invalid ones.  Using @cdhowie's solution will only clear the first failure, not all.

EDIT: You could even do something cool like setting the background color to red to visually highlight the bad textboxes (edited above code to show example).

Comment: ah this didn't include the fact that some of these values are int. As for changing the color, i intended to do so:)

Comment: @Sinaesthetic: you can try with a generic solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142752/c-try-catch-how-to-clear-the-text-box-that-caused-the-error/4142940#4142940

Comment: or i guess i could just overload this method

Comment: yeah, sorry I did it up quick and just did a double version.  You can easily parse doubles to ints or do a template/generic version.  Hope you enjoy :)

Comment: @Sinaesthetic: I hope that *"I could just overload this method"* doesn't mean to copy/paste it twice. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could declare a variable outside of the try block:

```
TextBox lastTextBox = null;
```

Then prior to each conversion, set this to the text box you will be fetching a value from, like so:

```
lastTextBox = txtXPos;
val1 = Convert.ToInt32(txtXPos.Text);
```

Then in your catch block:

```
if (lastTextBox != null)
    lastTextBox.Text = "";
```

Comment: awesome that works. is there any feasible way to do it for every incorrect box, or is that going to get too complicated?

Comment: You would probably have to rewrite much of the parsing logic.  Basically you would try each conversion (probably using int.TryParse et al instead of try/catch blocks) and clear each text box that failed.  You would also keep a main "success" variable that starts true and is set to false on the first conversion failure.  You would attempt all conversions even if one fails, but you would only display the error once you are done and have tested the success variable.

Comment: @sinaesthetic - Its goingg to complicate your code. Use `TryParse`.

Comment: @Sinaesthetic see my answer for a possible solution to this issue

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is Winforms, the best thing to do is probably to use the built-in [ErrorProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.aspx) rather than try to roll your own validation framework.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "Try Catch" blocks I will sugest you to use [Int32.TryParse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) and Double.TryParse

Answer (score 1):

The important point to note here is that you are using exceptions for non-exceptional circumstances. That is to say, the user entering an invalid number is not exceptional - it's almost expected!

You should be using the `TryParse` methods:

```
bool xValValid = Int32.TryParse(txtXPos.Text, out val1);
if(!xValValid){
  txtXPos.Text = "";
  validated = false;
  MessageBox.Show("You have an invalid value entered. Please check your entry.", "Invalid Values", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

}
```

Comment: I agree. But right now i have all text boxes subscribed to the same event as the first text box to avoid having to make 5 different TextChanged event. I could see how to incorporate this into that event if all of the text boxes were supposed to contain the same data type. Any ideas to make THAT work?

Comment: @sinaesthetic - All I can see are 4 textboxes, use the above code 4 times to check your 4 inputs, and clear the one(s) which have invalid data. Also, you can then do away with the `try..catch` block if you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can also extract the logic for a single text box into something like:

```
private bool Validated<T>(Control tb, out T value)
{
    try
    {
        value = return (T)Convert.ChangeType(tb.Text, typeof(T));
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        value = default(T);
        tb.Text = "";
        return false;
    }
 }
```

Which you could simply use as:

```
if (!Validated<int>(txtXPos, out val1) ||
    !Validated<int>(txtYPos, out val2) ||
    !Validated<double>(txtSpeed, out speed) ||
    !Validated<int>(txtDirection, out direction))
{
     MessageBox.Show("Validation failed");
}
```

**[Edit]**

Also, clearing the textboxes is a bad idea from usability point of view, especially inside `TextChanged` event. I wouldn't like my textbox being cleared if I accidentally type a letter inside. Much better way would be to use an ErrorProvider, or indicate unobtrusively that the input is wrong in some other way.

**[Edit2]**

Conversion from string to primitive types is possible using Convert.ChangeType, but you can supply any conversion method you like, if you need to parse a more complex string into a class of your own:

```
private bool Validated<T>(Control tb, Func<string, T> converter, out T value)
{
    try
    {
        value = converter(tb.Text);
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        value = default(T);
        tb.Text = "";
        return false;
    }
 }
```

And then use it like this:

```
if (!Validated<int>(txtXPos, Convert.ToInt32, out val1) ||
    !Validated<int>(txtYPos, Convert.ToInt32, out val2) ||
    !Validated<double>(txtSpeed, Convert.ToDouble, out speed) ||
    !Validated<int>(txtDirection, Convert.ToInt32, out direction))
{
        MessageBox.Show("Validation failed");
}
```

This way you can pass any delegate with the signature `Func<string, T>` which will do the actual conversion, or throw an exception if it fails.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private bool ValidateForm()
            {
                int val1, direction = 0;
                double speed = 0.0;

                bool validated;
                if (txtName.Text != "")
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //attempts to convert values into their primary data types. Any errors will throw an exception that will be reported as invalid data
                        int counter = 1;
                        val1 = Convert.ToInt32(txtXPos.Text);
                        counter = counter + 1;
                        val1 = Convert.ToInt32(txtYPos.Text);
                        counter = counter + 1;
                        speed = Convert.ToDouble(txtSpeed.Text);
                        counter = counter + 1;
                        direction = Convert.ToInt32(txtDirection.Text);
                        validated = true;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    switch(counter)

                      case 1:

                     txtXPos.Text="";
                      break;
                      case 2:

                      txtYPos.Text="";
                        break;
                      case 3:

                     txtSpeed.Text="";
                     break;
                     case 4:

                     txtDirection.Text="";
                      break;
                     default:
                     break;
                        MessageBox.Show("You have an invalid value entered. Please check your entry.", "Invalid Values", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        validated = false;
                    }
                    if (speed < 0.0 || speed > (double)newAirplane.PlanePosition.MaxSpeed)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Speed entered is out of range.", "Invalid Values", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        validated = false;
                    }
                    if (direction < 0 || direction > 359)
                        MessageBox.Show("Direction is out of range", "Invalid values", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a name.", "Blank Name", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    validated = false;
                }



                return validated;

            }
```

Think this is what you are expecting.